# Overwrite ui-datepicker-div primefaces

Tags: css, primefaces

I'm working with primefaces 6.2 and i wont to overwrite a class css for the popup calendar like this :[image]

But i have this :

[image]

So i added this class to my css file but i does'nt work!

```
.ui-datepicker-div {display: none !important;}
```

this my html code :

```
<p:calendar placeholder="#{msg.pattern_date_time_hour_minute}"
                                value="#{demandeMB.demautDatfinper}"
                                pattern="#{msg.pattern_date_time_hour_minute}"
                                locale="#{msg.local}" mask="true"
                                styleClass="calendar margin-left1em"
                                showButtonPanel="true"
                                showTodayButton="true"
                                navigator="true"
                    >
                        <p:ajax event="change"
                                listener="#{demandeMB.onDateFinChange}"
                                process="@this"
                                update="@this"
                                partialSubmit="true"
                                immediate="true"/>
                        <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
                                listener="#{demandeMB.onDateFinChange}"
                                process="@this"
                                update="@this"
                                partialSubmit="true"
                                immediate="true"/>
                    </p:calendar>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Comment: Moreover, you probably want to target the :focus selector on that div. The issue has more to do with CSS stylesheet rules and not so much with PrimeFaces.